# Mapeamento OneToOne JPA 2.2 Unidirecional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, orm

Olá, pessoal.

Estou utilizando JPA + hibernate 4 em cima da estrutura da base de dados (MySQL 5.6) abaixo. Estou em dúvida no relacionamento `@OneToOne`.

## O que está acontecendo:

A entidade `BodyPart` tem uma relação `@OneToOne` com `BodyPartHit` com carregamento *EAGER*. Na outra entidade, `BodyPartHit`, eu gostaria de ter apenas o `id` de `BodyPart`, conforme já está mapeado nas entidades abaixo. Ao persistir a entidade `BodyPart`, ela não persiste `BodyPartHit` mesmo estando com marcada com `CascadeType.All`. Daí tive que fazer da forma que geralmente é feito, persistindo a entidade pai e setando o `id` na entidade filha e funciona. Ao recuperar um objeto `BodyPart`, não é realizado o carregamento preguiçoso de `BodyPartHit`.

## O que eu gostaria se possível:

Manter o mapeamento das entidades abaixo, ter apenas o `idBodyPart` na entidade `BodyPartHit` e na entidade `BodyPart` ter uma referência `@OneToOne` para `BodyPartHit` com *CascadeType.All*, usando `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

## O que eu tentei pra solucionar o problema:

Eu verifiquei um post do [UaiHebert](http://uaihebert.com/jpa-onetoone-unidirectional-and-bidirectional/) falando um pouco sobre esse tipo de mapeamento, porém ele usa a anotação `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` que não necessita de um id na entidade filha (`BodyPartHit` no caso) pois a chave da entidade pai (`BodyPart`) é migrada para a filha, mas o problema deu utilizar essa abordagem é que tenho um id na tabela filha.

A base de dados (MySQL 5.6) está estruturada da seguinte forma:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `body_part` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `body_part_hit` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_body_part` INT NOT NULL,
  `perc_damage_hit` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_body_part_hit_1_idx` (`id_body_part` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_body_part_hit_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_body_part`)
    REFERENCES `body_part` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<ID> implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // get and set
}

Entity
@Table(name = "body_part")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPart")
public class BodyPart extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private BodyPartHit bodyPartHit;

    private String description;
    // get and set
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "body_part_hit")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPartHit")
public class BodyPartHit extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "perc_damage_hit")
    private BigDecimal percentDamageHit;

    @Column(name = "id_body_part)
    private Integer idBodyPart;

    // get and set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há como fazer.
Do jeito que você mapeou a classe, estaria correto se o lado que levasse a chave fosse o BodyPart, que não é o caso. Para conseguir fazer o relacionamento bidirecional, vc precisa mapear BodyPart em BodyPartHit, e então utilizar o mappedBy em BodyHit. JoinColumn é para ser usada na entidade que leva a chave, e não na que tem a chave transportada.
Veja esse post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Ficaria dessa forma

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "body_part")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPart")
public class BodyPart extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "bodyPart")
    private BodyPartHit bodyPartHit;

    private String description;
    // get and set
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "body_part_hit")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPartHit")
public class BodyPartHit extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "perc_damage_hit")
    private BigDecimal percentDamageHit;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_body_part", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private BodyPartHit bodyPart;

    // get and set
}
```

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86765)

Comment: Discordo, amigo.

Comment: Mesmo antes da edição não necessitava informações adicionais. Construção de conhecimento é mais importante que pontos, abraço.

Comment: @LeonardoLana Desculpe-me se a sua recepção ao StackOverflow em português foi um pouco turbulenta. Mas não desanime, sua contribuição é bem-vinda.

Comment: @LeonardoLana caso eu não consiga encontrar uma solução no contexto que expliquei na pergunta irei implementar dessa forma. Contudo, como utilizo essas entidades em uma resposta JSON, poderá ocorrer um problema de recursão infinita o qual há soluções que são/podem ser explanadas em outros tópicos.

Comment: Neste caso você anotaria, na classe BodyPart, o atributo com JsonManagedReference, e no Hit com Jsonbackreference

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar o problema, basta fazer uso da annotation @PrePersist, além de inverter o mapeamento das entidades (o @OneToOne deve estar na classe BodyPartHit.java)

BodyPartHit.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "body_part_hit")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPartHit")
public class BodyPartHit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "perc_damage_hit")
    private BigDecimal percentDamageHit;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_body_part", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private BodyPart bodyPart;

    @Column(name = "id_body_part", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idBodyPart;

    // equals, hashCode, toString, getters and setters
}
```

BodyPart.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "body_part")
@XmlRootElement(name = "bodyPart")
public class BodyPart {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "bodyPart")
    private BodyPartHit bodyPartHit;

    private String description;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if (bodyPartHit != null) {
            bodyPartHit.setBodyPart(this);
        }
    }

    // equals, hashCode, toString, getters and setters
}
```

Desta forma, quando o JPA persiste a entidade filha (BodyPartHit) via cascade, ele já irá possuir o id da entitdade pai (BodyPart).

Espero ter ajudado.

Segue um projeto exemplo que subi no github: https://github.com/enikolas/jpa-one-to-one-cascade

Comment: obrigado Nikolas, vou dar uma olhada depois, se der certo dou resolution na sua resposta.

Comment: @diegohsi por nada, aguardo o feedback em ver se isso resolve seu problema.